# Laravel 5.1 Api for Android

Tags: android, database, api, laravel

Hi I built a little Laravel 5.1 application, which just has a form with an database input.

I want to call that database within my android app to show the data.

I googeled and people talked about a Laravel API.

I could not find any good tutorial of how to use that Api to get later on the data of the database in my android app, so I ask here if anyone could explain me how that works or give me a good tutorial.

Comment: you have to export the data from your database into JSON or XML format so that you can parse the JSON or XML in android and display them

Comment: ok I understand that part, but I am not that experienced need some kind of tutorial of how to achiev this

Comment: this tutorial is in Greek language but if you see it is exactly what you need. check it out without listening just follow the code: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LcpVDSzDlms

Comment: Check out this package which helps making api in Laravel. https://github.com/dingo/api

Answer (score 0):

To connect android application with your database follow the below steps:

1- Create your RESTful API with Laravel: check the instruction in this [link](https://www.udemy.com/laravel-5-php-framework-agile-and-practical-php-restful-api/)

2- Use one of the REST client library for android like Retrofit to connect with your database. For more information check this [page](http://themakeinfo.com/2015/04/retrofit-android-tutorial/) or [this](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit) or the [official page for Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)